# Wicket - monitor all validation errors

Tags: forms, validation, wicket

is it possible to monitor all form/form-component validation errors in Wicket in one place? Is there some form of listener? I would like to have page, component and message of the error.

Thx for any help

Comment: Can you more specific? Are you using nested form kind of thing?

Comment: @Soora are you asking if my forms are nested classes in my pages?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very generic. What you are trying to achieve? Are you looking for some 'Admin' functionality to check Checked/RunTime exceptions or any kind of error including simple required field validation error?

Regardless, You can save the error messages into Session and have 'Admin' page displaying all the reported error messages in some tabular form. But those can't be real time as user might have already corrected the value.

You can also create your own ExceptionPage/Error Page and capture different types of Runtime errors **at the RequestCycle level** to capture and then display somewhere.

From design perspective, it would be easier for each page/component to push the error message into session store and then pulled all the reported error messages somewhere by using **Session.get().getFeedbackMessages().iterator()** to iterate over. When iterating over, you could then take benefit of FeedbackMessge's boolean methods like **isError(), isInfo()** etc for various display format on GUI.

Here is more information from Wicket (look for Overriding All Error Pages for RuntimeException section for session related snippet) :
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Error+Pages+and+Feedback+Messages

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FeedbackCollector#collect()` in a custom `IRequestCycleListener#onDetach()`. This will return you all `FeedbackMessage`s, not `ValidationError`s but it should do the job. If a feedback message is reported from `Component#error()` then you can reach it with `#getReporter()`.